# Connecting to WHM through API

Tags: php, api, cpanel, whm

Excuse me for my bad English :)

I'm trying to connect to WHM through API and Hash. I just used so many pre-coded scripts which i found on the Net. here are some of them:

http://www.zubrag.com/scripts/create-cpanel-whm-account.php
http://www.phpclasses.org/package/4150-PHP-Manipulate-Cpanel-WHM-accounts-using-its-XML-API.html
& ...

But no luck, because I couldn't get the result which I expect. I just want to get the response of WHM about my command. for example if i send an account creation request, I want to get this response: "Account Created Successfully" or "Account has not been created" (This responses will be sent by whm)

one of pre-coded scripts I've tested was returning the entire page of WHM in result and another one returns nothing at all :-S

You can review WHM SDK documentation in this address: (I've changed the URL to avoid posting links because of my reputation in StackOverflow):

docs[dot]cpanel[dot]net/twiki/bin/view/SoftwareDevelopmentKit/XmlApi

your helps are appreciated.
Thanks so much :)

Answer (score 1):

I would use the PHP WHM class from Cpanel Inc. It's available at github here https://github.com/CpanelInc/publicapi-php